# How can I fix the app's server to automate the usage of the project client's 'build' folder if a 'build' folder is present?

Tags: server, build, directory, resolve

What I would like:
I would like to make concise, efficient logic to retrieve and use a build folder, only if one is present (particularly when ready for hosting). Otherwise, the server should only use the files in the client.

Background (What I have now):
I'm currently working in my code editor.
I've commented out the code that uses the build folder in the path's URL since there is no need for a build folder at the moment.

```
const __dirname = path.resolve();
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => 
// res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html')))
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public/index.html')))
```

I haven't tried anything. I am assuming that someone may be able to present a quick if/else statement to help solve this. Please and thanks in advance!